# Is there a way to use the Dualshock 4 on a PC (ubuntu) with it not being picked up by the PS4?

Tags: controllers, ps4, ubuntu

I am trying to use a Dualshock 4 on my PC (Ubuntu 14.10) with Steam via USB. My problem is that whenever I long press the PS button my PS4 gets turned on (it's within range of the bluetooth).

How can I make sure the controller is assigned to the PC / USB and not have it interfere with the PS4.

I know I can refrain from long pressing the button, but was still wondering how to best circumvent this problem.

Comment: I am just curious why you need the PS Button at all? I can't think of any games that would require it. My only marginally helpful suggestion is just having it synced to a friends PS4 (or any PS4 that is out of range) instead.

Comment: Indeed I don't **need** it. But I used it to bring up Steam's Big Picture Mode and unknowingly turned on the PS4. :|

(Accidentally bought a game, too. Go figure.)

Answer (score 2):

You will have to change which device the Bluetooth module in the controller is paired to each time.

Input devices like controllers are typically designed to pair one-to-one with only one other device at a time. It would be very unusual for the controller's USB and Bluetooth systems to work together to control the wireless pairing.

Comment: Right. So if I want to play a game on Ubuntu via USB I need to un-pair my DS4 from the PS4. Is that it?

Comment: You'd need to pair it with your Ubuntu box if you wanted to use any of the buttons that invoke a Bluetooth feature, like the logo button.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it applies here but to put the DS4 in pairing mode hold down the Share button and press the PlayStation button until the light bar flashes. That will put the gamepad into pairing mode and should not start your PS4

Answer (score 0):

Steam has apparently related to my original question. They will soon [support the Dualshock 4 natively](https://www.engadget.com/2016/11/03/valve-is-testing-dualshock-4-support-in-steams-beta-channel/).